# HTML form select to drive PHP/SQLSRV results

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlsrv

I'm working on a very basic web page to facilitate data entry.  I have it working with PHP talking to SQL Server to both enter and display data.  At the simplest level, they'll select a store from a dropdown and enter some data, then hit submit.

I'm trying to dynamically display the last 7 days worth of data when their store is chosen from the form select input.  How do I get the Select value to drive the SQL query?  I found how to use onchange to fire a javascript function, which I can alert the value.  Do I really need to then use jquery or AJAX to link that back to the PHP select query or is there a simpler way to approach this?

I'm trying to learn this all from scratch and am quite admittedly out of my element.  Here are some snippets of what I've got:

```
...
<script>
    function OnSelectChange(obj)
    {
        alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
    }
</script>
...
<td align="right">Store</td><td width="125"><select style="width:100%" name="store" onchange="OnSelectChange(this)">
...
<?php
    $tsql = "select * from test where DateStamp >= getdate()-7";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    //generate table view of data
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>Store ID</td><td>Date</td><td>Data</td></tr>";
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
    {  
        $StoreID = $row['StoreID'];
        $DateStamp = $row['DateStamp'];
        $Donations = $row['Data'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$StoreID."</td><td>".$DateStamp."</td><td>".$Data."</td></tr>";
    }  
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I've found a lot of helpful information to get me this far, but am stuck now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A note:  The data sets would be so small that I'm not really needing to change the SQL query if I can just change what's displayed somehow.

Comment: I've had success assigning two classes.  One drives the initial CSS display:none, while the other allows me to toggle the display in a targeted manner.  Unfortunately, I'm using <tr>, so it's messing with how the table looks.  But it's working nicely otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  For anyone else looking, here are relevant snippets of code:

```
<style>
.hideable {
    visibility: collapse;
}
</style>

...

<script language="JavaScript">
    function OnSelectChange(cl)
    {
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName('hideable');
        for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i){
            var s = els[i].style;
            s.visibility = 'collapse';

        };
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
        for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i){
            var s = els[i].style;
            s.visibility = 'visible';
        };
    }
</script>

...

<select style="width:100%" name="store" onchange="OnSelectChange(this.value)">

...

echo "<tr class='hideable ".$StoreID."'><td>".$StoreID."</td><td>".$DateStamp."</td><td>".$Data."</td></tr>";
```

Leveraging dual classes upon the table (tr) creation and the collapse CSS style property was key.